# Why Isn't Port Listening in C++

Tags: c++, networking

I'm trying to set up a server using sockets, and the port I wish to be listened to seems to not be working properly. When I run the netstat -nlp command the port will not show up.

```
int openListenFd(int port){
        int socketDesc, newSocket;
        int opt = 1;
        struct  sockaddr_in server, client;
        string message;
        cout << "The port is " << port << endl;
        int myPort = 3207;
        socketDesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(socketDesc == -1){
                cout << "ERROR CREATING SOCKET DESCRIPTOR" << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(setsockopt(socketDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))){
                cout << "Setsocket error" << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        server.sin_port = htons(myPort);

        if(bind(socketDesc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){ 
                cout << "BIND FAILED" << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        cout << "Bind finished" << endl; //Page 982

        if(listen(socketDesc,10) < 0){
                close(socketDesc);
        }

        return socketDesc;

}
```

This should return the file descriptor for the connection, and it does not error at any point. It later gets to the accept() call where it simply waits, likely because no client can connect to it since the port isn't working.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I noticed this too and added exit(EXIT_FAILURE) to the code since then. It is not silently failing.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel indeed it is, I was trying many different port numbers for testing.

Comment: `if(setsockopt(...))` should be `if(setsockopt(...) < 0)`. And you can't set multiple options via a single `setsockopt()` call (ie using `SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT` is illegal), you need to set the options individually via separate calls

Comment: @RemyLebeau Very good to know! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that it is indeed not the code that was the issue. The reason the port was not showing up was that I was running it on a university Linux server, which had a virtual machine on it. As a result, the loopback address of 127.0.0.1 was not working properly. This probably could be fixed if I had administrator privileges on it, however, that is not the case.

The solution was to download ubuntu and run it within my own computer, thus making the loopback address valid.

Comment: Thanks for informing us of the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Works as expected for me. Test program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int openListenFd() {
    int socketDesc;
    int opt = 1;
    struct  sockaddr_in server;
    string message;
    int port = 3207;
    cout << "The port is " << port << endl;
    socketDesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socketDesc == -1){
            cout << "ERROR CREATING SOCKET DESCRIPTOR" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(setsockopt(socketDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))){
            cout << "Setsocket error" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(bind(socketDesc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
            cout << "BIND FAILED" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Bind finished" << endl; //Page 982

    if(listen(socketDesc,10) < 0){
            close(socketDesc);
    }

    return socketDesc;
}

int main() {
    int fd = openListenFd();
    int rc = system("netstat -tlnp");
    return !(fd && !rc);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3207              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      31807/test
```

Comment: It works for me too, under Microsoft Windows, after making slight adaptations for Winsock. For example, I had to remove the `setsockopt` call, because Winsock does not understand `SO_REUSEPORT`.

Comment: Interesting as it still won't work for me. I have tried it on both a Linux virtual machine and ubuntu now.